# Enabling mod_session_crypto hangs apache 2.4

Tags: httpd, apache-2.4, session, mod-auth

I want to try using session crypto on my apache installation so I uncomment the following line.

```
   #LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so
```

I restart apache and it gives me no errors. Then I browse to the site and I get nothing, just error.

> "Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a
>   problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client
>   authentication certificate that you don't have. Error code:
>   ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

The site is SSL only. Adding the comment back to my httpd.conf for mod_session_crypto returns the site to working order.

I am also receive the following error (repeatedly) in my error log when I load the crypto module.

```
[core:notice] [pid 16959:tid 139988902364992] AH00052: child pid 16971 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

When unloaded the error goes away. I'm using mod_auth_form and mod_session_cookie to authenticate a login, but I need crypto because the session cookie stores the username and password in plain text right in the browser cookie!

Why is crypto making my server halt?  I'm merely loading it, not even setting any of the additional variables required to make it work at this point.  How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after over a week I managed to come to a conclusion on the why part of my problem. Apache needs to be configured with --enable-session-crypto, in order for mod_session_crypto to work, as it is just an experimental package and not enabled by default. One would assume that since the module is available in the /modules folder that loadmodule would suffice but apparently it does not and apache needs to be rebuilt and re-installed to get this option.